# old hard drive: interpreting smartctl output

Tags: hardware-failure, smartd

I have been getting numerous e-mails from the 'smartd' daemon 
with Subject: 'SMART error (CurrentPendingSector)' 
saying that

```
The following warning/error was logged by the smartd daemon:
Device: /dev/sda, 1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
```

It sent me 80 such e-mails over several months.

I ran 'e2fsck -cc', 'smartctl' and 'gsmartcontrol'.

- 'e2fsck -cc' did not report any bad blocks.
- 'gsmartcontrol' highlited the following lines in the
  'smartctl' output:

`--`

```
ID   ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG   VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE    UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE  
...  
5    Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033  100   100   005  Pre-fail  Always      -   1179816  
...  
196  Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032  100   100   000    Old_age   Always      -   17  
197  Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022  100   100   000    Old_age   Always      -   1  
...
```

-- these are highlighted in pink by 'gsmartcontrol', not in red.

i.e.,  it reports 1,179,816  reallocated sectors (is it meaningful??), and 17 reallocation events.

Still, 'worst' is equal to the 'value'.

- /var/log/messages has occasional  messages

  `Jul 24 03:12:46 turtle smartd[1443]: Device: /dev/sda,

  1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors`

messages; total 38 in the last several days (!)

- `# smartctl -l error /dev/sda` reports several errors (below).

How do i interpret them? Should I replace the hard drive?

Thank you.

Detailed 'smartctl' output is below.

---

`# smartctl -H -A /dev/sda`

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16  

Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:  

ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE   

1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062 Pre-fail  Always       -       0  
2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   105   100   040 Pre-fail  Offline      -       4572  
3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   223   100   033 Pre-fail  Always       -       2  
4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   098   098   000 Old_age   Always       -       3671  
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005 Pre-fail  Always       -       1179816  
7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067 Pre-fail  Always       -       0  
8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   120   100   040 Pre-fail  Offline      -       40  
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   030   030   000 Old_age   Always       -       30819  
10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060   Pre-fail  Always       -       0  
12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000  Old_age   Always       -       2205  
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   095   000  Old_age   Always       -       1  
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000  Old_age   Always       -       97  
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   001   001   000  Old_age   Always       -       1865772  
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   177   100   000  Old_age   Always       -       31 (Lifetime Min/Max 9/48)  
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000  Old_age   Always       -       17  
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000  Old_age   Always       -       1  
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000  Old_age   Offline      -       0  
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   190   000 Old_age   Always       -       38
```

`

`# sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda`

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===  
Model Family:     Hitachi Travelstar 5K100 series  
Device Model:     HTS541060G9AT00  
Serial Number:    MPB3LAX5KUDB1M  
Firmware Version: MB3OA60A  
User Capacity:    60,011,642,880 bytes  
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]  
ATA Version is:   6  
ATA Standard is:  ATA/ATAPI-6 T13 1410D revision 3a  
..  
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.  
SMART support is: Enabled
```

- `# smartctl -l error /dev/sda`

  `=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===

  SMART Error Log Version: 1

  ATA Error Count: 80 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)

  CR = Command Register [HEX]

  FR = Features Register [HEX]

  SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]

  SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]

  CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]

  CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]

  DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]

  DC = Device Command Register [HEX]

  ER = Error register [HEX]

  ST = Status register [HEX]

   Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as

  DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
  SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.`

  `Error 80 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 28086 hours (1170 days + 6 hours)

   When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.`

  `After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH

  ---

  40 51 3f 50 28 2c e1  Error: UNC 63 sectors at LBA = 0x012c2850 = 19671120`

  `Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name

  ---

  c8 ff 3f 50 28 2c e1 00      04:33:56.000  READ DMA
  c8 ff 3f 00 00 00 e0 00      04:33:56.000  READ DMA
  c6 ff 10 00 02 00 a0 00      04:33:56.000  SET MULTIPLE MODE
  10 ff 3f 01 00 00 ae 00      04:33:56.000  RECALIBRATE [OBS-4]
  91 ff 3f 01 00 00 ae 00      04:33:56.000  INITIALIZE DEVICE PARAMETERS [OBS-6]
  Error 79 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15200 hours (633 days + 8 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.
  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH

  ---

  84 51 00 ae 3e 2f e4  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x042f3eae = 70205102`

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name

  ---

  c8 00 08 a7 3e 2f e4 00      00:00:30.600  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 af 62 2c e4 00      00:00:30.600  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 af 61 2c e4 00      00:00:30.600  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 af 60 2c e4 00      00:00:30.600  READ DMA
  c8 00 00 af 5f 2c e4 00      00:00:30.600  READ DMA

  Error 78 occurred ...

Answer (score 0):

Every HDD has a number of unused sectors that are preserved from the factory for the relocation events. Once HDD firmware detects unreadable sector it "replaces" it with the healthy one "from the stock". In fact, nothing is really moved, it only records that instead of sector xxx sector yyy must be used. This is called sector relocation event.

If it started to happen that means that HDD is not healthy, it's surface started degradation, the number of relocated sectors will increase in the future depending on how heavily HDD is used.
So far, you can relax you can still work with this HDD, but you need to monitor the relocation progress and consider to replace HDD in the future.